# Adobe Air windows that don't show up on taskbar (I dont mean UTILITY or LIGHTWEIGHT)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex3

I want to create a new Adobe AIR window from my application. I want the new window to be a normal new window but not to re-size, minimize, or maximize but I also don't want it to show up on the task bar. In other words, I want it to be like a browser's alert window. Look carefully when you look at one of those, the type of window is not a utility window.

Comment: see here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.1/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e09.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the link posted by Cay, there are only [three types](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html#type) of windows: normal, utility and lightweight. Normal windows do show up on the taskbar. So if you don't wanna use utility or lightweight, I guess you'd have to live with the taskbar.

Comment: I feared that would be the answer... I guess the only way for me to get that kind of detailed window managing would be through native programming leaving my WORA abilities at a standstill... Thank you.